# Remove Function on Doubly Linked List

Tags: c++, pointers, delete-operator, doubly-linked-list

I'm trying to get my remove function to work for a doubly linked list. I feel like my code is correct, but it keeps breaking. I believe it has something to do when I delete the node but I'm not sure the compiler keeps taking me to a throw.cpp? So I'm not quite sure whats wrong. Here is my code:

```
  ItemType remove(int index) 
  {
    ItemType name;
    Node* temp;
    Node* current;
    int pos = 0;
    int endpos = size - 1;

    if (index >= 0 && index <= size)
    {
        if (index == 0)
        {
            temp = head;
            delete head;
            head = temp->next;
            size--;
            name = temp->info;
            return name;
        }
        else if (index == size - 1)
        {
            temp = tail;
            delete tail;
            tail = temp->prev;
            size--;
            name = temp->info;
            return name;
        }
        else if (index <= size/2)
        {
            current = head;
            while (pos != index)
            {
                current = current->next;
                pos++;
            }
        }
        else if (index > size/2)
        {           
            current = tail;
            while (endpos != index)
            {
                current = current->prev;
                endpos--;
            }
        }
    }

    temp = current;
    current->prev->next = current->next;
    current->next->prev = current->prev;
    delete current;
    size--;
    name = temp->info;
    return name;


  }
```

if anyone can see what might be the problem that would be sweet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the error?

Some suggestion, when deleting the head and tail, set the new head/tail pointer first before deleting the old one. So the code

```
 temp = head;
 delete head;
 head = temp->next;
```

should be changed to

```
 temp = head;
 head = temp->next;
 delete temp;
```

Do the same for the tail. This is because when you call `delete head`, the `temp` which is pointing the same location with `head` now have garbage values, so you can't just use `temp->next` in the subsequent commands.

Also when calling `name = temp->info`, make sure it is before the variable is deleted.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you. Do I need to assign anything to NULL, like for example if I have a list and end up deleting the whole list one node at a time?

Comment: Setting `head` and `tail` to `NULL` when the list is all deleted is also a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

Here are few corrections

instead of this

```
if (index >= 0 && index <= size)
```

use

```
 if (index >= 0 && index < size)
```

You are deleting the node before updating the pointer thats why this will crash. So first you need to update head pointer then delete temp. Like this

```
temp = head;
head = head->next;
delete temp;
```

same applies while deleting the tail pointer also

```
temp = tail;
tail = tail->next;
delete temp;
```

Here delete temp not current

```
temp = current;
current->prev->next = current->next;
current->next->prev = current->prev;
delete temp;
```

and use

```
name = current->info;
```